# Mysterious shell sub-prompt when importing local module itself containing imports

Tags: python, shell, import

When trying to import a local module at the Python shell command prompt, I get a second prompt, as so:

```
-----------------
>>> import mymod
In: 
-----------------
```

This turns out to be caused by an import statement in mymod for the ipdb module:

```
./mymod.py:
import ipdb
...
```

Now the ipdb module is in the site-packages directory which again is in sys.path, and there is no problem importing it when running the module as a script.

So: What is this prompt asking me for, why does it not just find the requested module or issue a 'no module named xxx error'. And: If I just want to leave this prompt to the main prompt, what key or command do I use.
(**and yes I don't need ipdb when importing mymod in shell, but just wanted to understand what's going on**).

Note: this is on Python 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) is an interactive python debugger and shell. This essentially gives you a prompt where you can interactively debug your code. It gives you access to the "globals" and "locals" at that point in it's execution. (*You get a Python Interactive Shell*).

Normally however it should only take effect when you see:

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

So find the `ipdb.set_trace()` line and comment it out or remove it.

Comment: I said it above it's not an issue. What is the prompt asking for.

Comment: I explained that. It gives you an interactive debugging shell. A Python Shell with the globals and locals at that point in the execution.

Comment: Thx, It actually takes effect by the contained import statement, without a set_trace() call.